# If this is in the string and it causes the error, return error message - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement

So, I am currently relearning python through a series of mini projects and I am a lil bit stuck. My current issue involves a function taking in a string of numbers and operators, much like a calculator. I've set up a function that tries to do the calculation, except when a SyntaxError is produced. I want to create specific error messages for different circumstances but have no idea how to do it. My current format is of the following (say for too many decimal points):

```
try:
    #Does the calculation
except SyntaxError:
    for element in string:
        if element == '.' and SyntaxError:
            # Print the specified error message here
        elif element == '(' or element == ')' and SyntaxError:
            # Print another, but unique error message here
```

Currently, if the error was produced it would take the first character of the input and just return the error message associated for that first character. What I want it to do is identify what character is causing the error and then use that to print the correct error message. For now, if I input "o..45" into the program, it prints nothing as I don't have anything for a SyntaxError and a 0. I would ideally like it to instead print "You have inserted too many decimal points, please try again." I hope I explained this okay!

Comment: What do you expect `and SyntaxError` to do? Please provide a [mre] so that we can understand what you're trying to do and how it goes wrong. Your question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: If you really want to provide a specific message for every possible error, that seems like a lot of work to do for such a simple project. You'd have to essentially design and lay out a huge flowchart of every possible syntax error, figure out how to detect each one (from a combo of interpreting the error message from Python along with parsing the text itself), and then implement all that as Python code. It's not impossible, but seems very time consuming. Like, what do you do when there are multiple errors? Or if the error is not clear? I think displaying a generic message would be sufficient.

Comment: ...That is very true! I will just display a general message then, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem differently. Instead of trying to catch the errors, make some input validation prior to the point where the program hits the error.
Maybe try a string function such as isanum() to validate whether the string is alpha numeric.
for example:

```
def get_integer(prompt):
    while True:
        entry = input(prompt)
        if entry.isanum():
            return int(entry)
        else:
            print("Invalid entry; try a number")
            continue
```